# TabController for handling opening and closing of tabs

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a class `TabController` to handle opening and closing of tabs. It needs some data from my `viewModel`, so should I pass in the viewmodel via the constructor or is that overkill? It really only needs the parameters `browserCollection` and `activeWindow`, so I could just pass those two in if that's better. I'm just starting learning about design patterns so I can code well but am having trouble wiring everything up.

```
public abstract class TabController
{
    ViewModel vm;

    #region constructor
    public TabController(ViewModel vm)
    {
        this.vm = vm;
    }
    #endregion

    public abstract void go(Uri address);
    public abstract void newTabGo(Uri address);
    public abstract void newEmptyTab();

    public void newTab(Uri address, int insertionIndex)
    {
        vm.browserCollection.Insert(insertionIndex, new MyBrowserControl(address));
    }
}

//first class, starts out this way when the program starts -- no tabs are open
public class NoTabsOpen : TabController
{
    ViewModel vm;

    #region constructor
    public NoTabsOpen(ViewModel vm)
        : base(vm)
    {
        this.vm = vm;
    }
    #endregion

    public override void go(Uri address)
    {
        if (address != null)
            vm.browserCollection.Add(new MyBrowserControl(address));
    }

    public override void newTabGo(Uri address)
    {
        if (address != null)
            base.newTab(address, 0);
    }

    public override void newEmptyTab()
    {
        base.newTab(null, 0);
    }

}

//second class - active when at least one tab is open
public class TabsOpen : TabController
{
    ViewModel vm;

    #region constructor
    public TabsOpen(ViewModel vm)
        : base(vm)
    {
        this.vm = vm;
    }
    #endregion

    public override void go(Uri address)
    {
        if (address != null)
        {
            MyBrowserControl mbc = vm.browserCollection[vm.activeWindow];
            mbc.mySource = address;
        }
    }

    public override void newTabGo(Uri address)
    {
        if (address != null)
        base.newTab(address, vm.activeWindow + 1);
    }

    public override void newEmptyTab()
    {
        base.newTab(null, vm.activeWindow + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> public TabsOpen(ViewModel vm)
>     : base(vm)
> {
>     this.vm = vm;
> }
> ```

There's no reason to set `this.vm = vm` here. You're already doing that by passing the argument to your base class' constructor. Both of your subclass ctors could look like this.

```
public TabsOpen(ViewModel viewModel)
  : base (viewModel) { }
```

I changed the parameter name to make it a bit clearer. Speaking of naming, it's a convention in C# to PascalCase method names. You've camel cased yours. It's consistent though, so I can't gripe too much about it.

To address your actual question though, typically yes, you will pass your view model to the controller as you've done here. However, that's because the controller is typically updating the view. That doesn't seem to be the case here, so the thought comes to mind that it is better to only inject what you actually need.

I like that you've used polymorphism to simulate the state of an object, but it makes me wonder if what you have here is really a view model and not some other concept.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the TabController class is adding items to BrowserCollection, which is an ObservableCollection that is the ItemsSource for a Gridview in the UI. So I guess it is updating a little bit of the viewmodel. I am tending to migrate a lot of my code to the view model instead of the code behind... I will have to review the View Model concepts. Just learned basic Factory Design pattern today, interesting stuff.

Comment: I notice that when I use a factory class however, it adds another layer where I have to pass the arguments a second time.

Is it okay to just make the BrowserCollection and ActiveWindow static in the viewmodel class? There is only one of each. That way I can skip passing them around and just get them directly... but it kind of feels like cheating as if I'm using a public variable or something?

Comment: No. Don't use static variables like that. It makes for code that's difficult to test. Passing objects around is fine. That's what we should be doing. I think you have a noble goal of moving the code out of the code behind. It's a great step in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

What pattern are you following? Normally with MVC the controller constructs and populates view models and instructs the View to render them.

Also with from what I can tell you're misusing inheritance, NoTabsOpen and and TabsOpen is a *state* of the View-Model and you shouldn't be switching controllers based on state, a controller is a resource (in the web world represented by a url) that consumes state.

I would recommend:

```
public class TabController
{
     private ViewModel Model{get;set;}
     public TabController(ViewModel vm)
     {
         this.vm = vm;
     }
     public void Go(Uri address)
     {
        if(vm.HasTabs)
        {
           //Load into active tab
        }
        else
        {
          //Create new tab and load
        }
     }
 }
```

Also I noticed you're using ObservableCollection which leads me to believe this is WPF, you should really look into MVVM as it's a much better pattern for WPF.

Comment: Yes, it's WPF, I am trying to use MVVM. I only called the class TabController because it controls the tabs, I didn't realize the word Controller was an important word.